# Image control not being populated by binary data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an image for every student recorded in the database. However when ever l want to show details of a student. All the other stuff is shown besides the image. My code shows no run-time errors or debugging errors. The Id input for the method is the student number entered so as to show information show that student.

```
private void Image(string id)
{
    byte[] bytes = (byte[])GetData("SELECT Image FROM SI WHERE  Username=" + id).Rows[0]["Image"];
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    imgPic.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
}

private DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tlcString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: And if username is a string then you should add quotes around that _id_ but better to learn what an Sql Injection could do to your db

Comment: Are you sure data URI's are supported on the `ImageUrl` property?

Comment: If you use SqlCommand and SqlConnection, you are NOT using the MySql database, and this question was tagged wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a completely separate ashx handler or aspx page for this that expects an ID in the URL and does something like the following on page load:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
    byte[] bytes = (byte[])GetData("SELECT Image FROM SI WHERE  Username=" + ID;
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
}
```

Then the `ASP:Image` in your current page can have a conventional URL more like this:

```
private void Image(string id)
{
    imgPic.ImageUrl = "mynewpage.ashx?ID=" + id;
}
```

## **But don't do exactly this!**

This is crazy-vulernable to Sql Injection attacks. It's practically begging to get you hacked. The problem is in the `GetData()` method, which lacks any mechanism to parameterize your queries. The method as is effectively forces you to write bad code. You need to change the method to something more like this:

```
private DataTable GetData(string query, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tlcString"].ConnectionString;

    //You can stack these up
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        foreach(var p in parameters)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

         sda.Fill(dt);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

And now you can change the Page_Load() to do this:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var userID = new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.Int);
    userID.Value = Request.QueryString["ID"];

    byte[] bytes = (byte[])GetData("SELECT Image FROM SI WHERE  Username= @Username", userID).Rows[0]["Image"];
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
}
```

When that is done — **AND THIS IS IMPORTANT!** — go back and check everywhere else that uses the `GetData()` method to make sure you fix any other places that use string concatenation to put data into a query. This is so important, you might even want to skip the `params` option on the method, to force a compile error for any query that's not explicitly creating a parameter array, but be ***sure*** you get them all.

Comment: Thank you for the help. However lm a little bit confused with your code. Firstly its showing me an error with the Request.QueryString("ID"). It says querystring cant be used a method. Secondly, do l discard my Image method because lm struggling to understand how lm going to get input for the student number. I understand the code but lm just struggling on how to use it. Help will be appreciated thank you. @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: @KelvinNkomo The question I answered just before this was VB, and I used the VB indexer syntax for Request.QueryString. It's fixed now. I also added context for how to use the code.